# Duplicated similar question, is that a known bug?

Tags: bug, similar-questions

When typing a question, I see the "Similar questions" and at times it gets duplicated.

It's there twice. When it happens and I scroll up/down, I can see two slider bar on the right (not well represented in screenshot).

[image]

I can just close and reopen the section and it gets fixed. But I have the latest Linux 18.04 Firefox so I would think that it should work like a charm, right? (Firefox v70.0.1)

Here is another screenshot that better shows the fact that there are two slider bars on the right side:

[image]